# Bidirectionally @OneToMany mapped objects (parent & child): parent gets saved, child does not

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-onetomany

I have two entites mapped bidirectionally @OneToMany (I guess this is the right way to do so):

```
@Entity
@Table(name="entry")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Entry {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique=true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entry", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonManagedReference
//    @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId=true)
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    .....
}

@Entity
@Table(name="address")
public class Address {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Null
    private String line1;

    @Null
    private String line2;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entry_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Entry entry;

    ....

}
```

When I debug the object (`Entry`) just before it's sent to be saved, I can see that it contains an array (`ArrayList` type) of `Address`es. However, each (at this moment, the only) element of that address list contains `Entry` as its attribute, and so on - they are infinitely nested.

Note: In this situation `Entry` still does not have an `id` assigned. So I tried first to `persist(entry)` and then do `address.add(entry)`, and finally `flush()`. **That didn't help** in regards to what is said below to be the real problem.

My questions is: Is this normal?

I'm asking because when I save the `Entry` object, only the parent (`Entry`) record is created, and `Address` is not. I even suspected that there is no way for `Address` to be saved so I went ahead and created a repository interface for it. **That didn't help either**.

Answer (score 2):

I just found out what the problem was. I started with `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` option in my `Entry` entity but removed it later and forgot to put it back. I didn't even know that was what saving the child object depends on. So, lesson learned, I hope someone else finds this helpful.

Comment: Just in case, you have more options than "all" and no one, check this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CascadeType.html